# How to delete all messages from SQS Queue at once Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

According to the Amazon documentation, the code to delete a single message from the SQS Queue is:

```
    // Delete a message
System.out.println("Deleting a message.\n");
String messageReceiptHandle = messages.get(0).getReceiptHandle();
sqs.deleteMessage(new DeleteMessageRequest()
    .withQueueUrl(myQueueUrl)
    .withReceiptHandle(messageReceiptHandle));
```

However, say I have more than 20 or so messages, do I really have to process this for every single message? Or is there a way to do a batch delete?

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: Why the downvote? It seems a good question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at the API for doing something similar [DeleteMessageBatchRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/model/DeleteMessageBatchRequest.html) seems to do the trick.

Comment: Ah, I thought there may have been docs, but I couldn't find what I was looking for. Cheers for that

Answer (score 6):

If you want to delete all messages you don't need batch delete, you should Purge the queue like so:

```
var request = new Amazon.SQS.Model.PurgeQueueRequest
{
    QueueUrl = "your queue url"
};
_sqsClient.PurgeQueue(request);
```

Purging a queue removes all the messages already in the queue

Answer (score 1):

For completeness as this Q&A comes up still when searching and Java 2 API examples are hard to find, here is the purge example in Java:

```js
SqsClient sqs = SqsClient.builder()
         .region(Region.EU_WEST_1)
         .credentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsProvider.create("default"))
         .build();


PurgeQueueRequest pqRequest = PurgeQueueRequest.builder()
            .queueUrl("your SQS queu URL (not ARN!)")
            .build();

sqs.purgeQueue(pqRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [SDK documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/AmazonSQSClient.html), you will see a `deleteMessageBatch` method which takes a list of messages.